# JQuery Autocomplete select undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, jquery-autocomplete

I've been ripping my hair out for a few hours now and can't seem to find out why i've got an error.

When i call the following code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#searchBox").attr("readonly", true);

                //this is where if i call alert(ui.long) I get undefiend

                $("#CoorLong").val(ui.long);
                $("CoorLat").val(ui.lat);
                print_r(ui);
            },
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        key: "bingKey",
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    jsonp: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = data.resourceSets[0];
                        if (result) {
                            if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                                response($.map(result.resources, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        data: item,
                                        label: item.name + '[' + item.point.coordinates[0] + ' ' + item.point.coordinates[1] + ']' + ' (' + item.address.countryRegion + ')',
                                        value: item.name,
                                        long: item.point.coordinates[0],
                                        lat: item.point.coordinates[1]
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

As I said in the selec: function(event, ui) when i call ui.item or ui.value or ui.long I always get undefined

I implemented a print_r() to check the content and I do get this :

[item] =>object

- [data] =>object
  - [__type] =>Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1
  - [bbox] =>object
    - [0] =>48.83231728242932
    - [1] =>2.2598159619433122
    - [2] =>48.840042717570675
    - [3] =>2.275464038056688
- [name] =>Quai d'Issy-les-Moulineaux, 75015 Paris
- [point] =>object
  - [type] =>Point
  - [coordinates] =>object
    - [0] =>48.83618
    - [1] =>2.26764

[address] =>object

- [addressLine] =>Quai d'Issy-les-Moulineaux
- [adminDistrict] =>IdF
- [adminDistrict2] =>Paris
- [countryRegion] =>France
- [formattedAddress] =>Quai d'Issy-les-Moulineaux, 75015 Paris
- [locality] =>Paris
- [postalCode] =>75015

[confidence] =>Medium

[entityType] =>RoadBlock

[label] =>Quai d'Issy-les-Moulineaux, 75015 Paris[48.83618 2.26764] (France)

[value] =>Quai d'Issy-les-Moulineaux, 75015 Paris

[long] =>48.83618

[lat] =>2.26764

So i don't understand why it's undefined.

Thank you :)

Comment: It appears that the only property you can expect `ui` to have is `ui.item`. You sure that's `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-select):

```
ui.item refers to the selected item.
```

So I think you want `ui.item.long` instead of `ui.long`.

Comment: Thanks, i've been at it since 8am, and thought i had already tried that, but mustn't have. Cheers ;)